# google sheets - Help in limiting script to apply on specific range

Tags: google-sheets, row, show-hide

```
function hideRows() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  for(var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) 
 { 
  if(data[i][0] !== "EFG")
    {sheet.showRows(i + 1);}
  if(data[i][0] === "EFG")
    {sheet.hideRows(i + 1);}
  }
}
```

Need help in limiting this to APPLY to A2:A20 ONLY

Comment: changed **for(var i = 1; i < data.length; i++)**   to **for(var i = 2; i < 20; i++)** and it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

changed `for(var i = 1; i < data.length; i++)` to `for(var i = 2; i < 20; i++)` and it worked. –